# Get ACF value after update user using save_post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

How to get the value of ACF after clicking update user in User menu.
I have the following code but it's not working:

```
function get_acf_value ($post_id) {
    $v = get_field('field_5b1d13fce338d', $post_id);
    echo $v;
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'get_acf_value' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working but its not going to print to the screen anything because save_post running in ajax. You can debug the action with the `error_log()`.

First in the wp-config.php you need to turn debug and set it to log into file instead of display

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

It will create you a file in the folder wp-content in the name debug.log

And then you can use `error_log()` to debug like this:

```
function get_acf_value ($post_id) {
    $v = get_field('field_5b1d13fce338d', $post_id);
    error_log($v);
    // Incase it is array you can use print_r
    error_log( print_r( $v, true ) );
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'get_acf_value' );
```

Comment: That's not exactly true. It depends on how should this code work...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Please explain...

Comment: I've added an answer with my explanation :)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I know this but it not why his code not working his `echo`... I know its risky to use the 10 as priority but its wasn't the problem in his code.

Comment: It depends what the problem exactly is - I really don't believe that all that OP was trying to achieve was to echo that value ;) That's why I don't say your answer is incorrect. I just say it's not full and I'm posting my as another possible reason why it's not working like it should :)

Answer (score 1):

As Shibi already stated, echoing the value during `save_post` or `acf/save_post` doesn't make much sense, since you won't see much of your output. But I don't think echoing it is the thing you want to do with this value. I'm guessing it's just some way of debugging?

But, there is one more problem with your code. Most probably it will return previous value for given field. Why? ACF doc [offers some explanation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/).

> This filter allows you to hook in before or after the data has been
>   saved. It is important to note that the get_field() function will
>   return different values at these times (previous value / new value).

So if you'll use priority less than 10, you will get previous value for given field.

```
function get_acf_value ($post_id) {
    $v = get_field('field_5b1d13fce338d', $post_id);
    // $v contains old value of field 'field_5b1d13fce338d'
    echo $v;
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'get_acf_value', 1 ); // <- priority is 1
```

And if you'll use priority greater than 10, you will get new value for that field.

```
function get_acf_value ($post_id) {
    $v = get_field('field_5b1d13fce338d', $post_id);
    // $v contains new value of field 'field_5b1d13fce338d'
    echo $v;
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'get_acf_value', 20 ); // <- priority is 20
```

Using it with priority equal to 10 is a little bit risky - most probably it will get you old or new value, depending on when your hook is assigned.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, however how can i see the acf value that has been updated?

Comment: and also, i want to put a condition if the update is triggered only in users panel

Comment: Where do you want to show it? You can't echo it during `save_post` - it won't be shown anywhere on the website in such case...

Comment: ok, i managed it by using debug log, my last question is how could i condition it only in users screen/panel?

Comment: @NikkoDelaCruz and do you have any post editors on front-end? Usually posts are saved only in backend by users.

Comment: i mean in the backend, if the admin triggered the update user button.

Comment: @NikkoDelaCruz ok, but who else can do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78769/discussion-between-nikko-dela-cruz-and-krzysiek-drozdz).

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding fields IDs is considered generally bad idea, because it will work only if you export and import your fields, and you're hardcoding ACF's implementation details into your code. Much less volatile solution is to use field's name.

Let's say your field name is `is_allowed_to_make_reviews`. You can use the code below to hook when field is saved and do anything you need with it's value.

```php
function update_is_allowed_to_make_reviews($user_id)
{
    if (is_admin() === false) { // if you want it to work only in wp_admin
        return;
    }

    if ($_POST['_acf_screen'] !== 'user') { // to not fire it on other screens
        return;
    }

    $value = get_field('is_allowed_to_make_reviews', $user_id);

    echo $value;
}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_is_allowed_to_make_reviews', 100);
```